# Laravel basic routing not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I am following the Laravel tutorial on [TutorialsPoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_routing.htm) and I am now in the basic routing section, however I can't seem to get the first function to work (the below code in my `app/Http/routes.php` file

```
Route::get('ID/{id}',function($id){
   echo 'ID: '.$id;
});
```

When I enter in the URL http://localhost:8000/ID/5 I get the below error

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 533
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 512
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 498
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 174
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 30
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in TransformsRequest.php line 30
at TransformsRequest->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ValidatePostSize.php line 27
at ValidatePostSize->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 149
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 116
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Am I missing something that I didn't do?

NOTE: I didn't have a `route.php` in my `app/Http` folder, and I added it myself.

If I am missing information that may help, please tell me so I can put them.

Comment: I read in another question that I should use `php artisan serve` but this too didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial you are using is based on Laravel 5.1 and if you did not specify the version during the project initialization process your Laravel project should be using the latest one, which is 5.4. (you can check the version you are using by executing the command 
`php artisan --version` in your Laravel project folder.

The problem with that is, that the routing mechanism was changed in version 5.3 and therefore the routing information is now located in the folder "routes" (split across three files: web, api, console). (please see https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing for more information)

To use your route, you just need add your example route to the web.php file.

Hope that helps!

Best regards
Tek

Comment: That is true, I didn't notice the difference in the laravel versions, I am using 5.4. Thanks for the link